# Check Session Variable in Jade View

Tags: node.js, express, pug, passport.js

Im using NodeJS, ExpressJS, PassportJS and Jade.

I have a header menu which will display login or logout. Login is displayed if the user is not yet logged in, and Logout if the user is already logged in.

The menu is in separate jade file: `menu.jade` and included in the rest of jade files.

```
include menu
```

In menu.jade how can I check if the user already logged in? Can I check session variable in jade? Something like below for `menu.jade`?

```
if ( req.session.name != null)
    a(href='/logout') Logout
else
    a(href='/login') Login
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You need to expose session to the templates. The way I do it, is that I put my user variable into locals:

Note: req.user is set by passportJS, you can see their example on it from [here (in the bottom)](http://passportjs.org/guide/authorize/)
Note #2: More on locals [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals)

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  // put user into res.locals for easy access from templates
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;

  next();
});
```

and then in the template you can do this:

```
- if(_user) {
    div.menuForLoggedInUser
- } else {
    div.menuForLoggedOutUser
- }
```

If you don't feel like exposing the whole user object to the templates, feel free to just put "loggedIn" to locals and check that... Something like this then:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  // just use boolean for loggedIn
  res.locals.loggedIn = (req.user) ? true : false;

  next();
});
```

Edit: Thanks to [robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep) for pointing out res.locals vs app.locals

Comment: I believe you also need to actually expose app.locals as locals when rendering the view. (node.js and express mostly avoid 'magic')

Comment: My implementation was indeed a bit flawed. Instead of app.locals = {}; it should be app.locals({}); (as expressJS documentation states)

Comment: `app.locals` is an application wide storage, you shouldn't use it to store dynamic data like `req.user` (because other requests might overwrite it). Use [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals) instead.

Comment: I think you have done one typo, write `if(user)` instead of `if(_user)`

Answer (score 1):

I will bring variable that result for check logged in.

```
// routes/some.js
exports.index = function (req, res) {
    res.render('somepage', {
        isAlreadyLoggedin: checkSessionSomeway()
    })
}

// menu.jade
if ( isAlreadyLoggedin != null)
    a(href='/logout') Logout
else
    a(href='/login') Login
```